# find env variables for a all builds for a job on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-scriptler

I need to monitor what are the changes going with a job on jenkins(update the changes to a file). Need to list the env variables of a job. JOB_NAME,BUILD_NUMBER,BUILD_STATUS,GIT_URL for that build(all the builds of a job). I didn't find out a good example with the groovy. What is the best way to fetch all the info?

Comment: are you trying to run `groovy` script as a build step?

Comment: @pArAs  yes. I'm trying to run a groovy script to find all env variables of build.

Answer (score 1):

`build.getEnvironment(listener)` should get you what you need

Comment: Please add some example.  It will help visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you would like to achieve there are at least several approaches to retrieve and save environment variables for:

- current build
- all past builds

## Get environments variables for current build (from slave)

Execute Groovy script

```
// Get current environment variables and save as 
// a file in $WORKSPACE.
new File(".",'env.txt').withWriter('utf-8') { writer ->
  System.getenv().each { key, value ->
    writer.writeLine("${key}:${value}")
  }
}
```

Using [Groovy Plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin).

## Get environment variables for current build (from master)

Execute system Groovy script

```
// Get current environment variables and save as 
// a file in $WORKSPACE.
import hudson.FilePath


def path = "env-sys.txt" 
def file = null

if (build.workspace.isRemote()) {
   file = new FilePath(build.workspace.channel, build.workspace.toString() + "/" + path)
} else {
   file = new FilePath(build.workspace.toString() + "/" + path)
}

def output = ""
build.getEnvironment(listener).each { key, value ->
  output += "${key}:${value}\n"
}
file.write() << output
```

Using [Groovy Plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin).

Environment variables returned by Groovy scripts are kept in map. If you don't need all of them, you can access individual values using standard [operators/methods](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-get-value-from-map-or.html?m=1).

## Get environment variables for all past builds (from master)

This approach expecst that you have installed [EnvInject Plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin,) and have access to $JENKINS_HOME folder:

```
$ find . ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/[path-to-your-job] -name injectedEnvVars.txt
...
```

ps. I suspect that one could analyze [EnvInject Plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin,) API and find a way to extract this information directly from Java/Groovy code.

Using [EnvInject Plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin,).

To look for only specific variables you can utilize [find, grep and xargs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21033/how-can-i-grep-the-results-of-find-using-exec-and-still-output-to-a-file) tools .

Comment: Everything looks great. I've one question. What is the function to get values for specific env variables(for eg: GIT_BRANCH)? instead of print all env variables.

Comment: You can used named indexing to get a specific environment variable, e.g. `build.getEnvironment(listener)["GIT_BRANCH"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use below script to get the `Environment Variables`

```
def thread = Thread.currentThread()
def build = thread.executable
// Get build parameters
def buildVariablesMap = build.buildVariables 
// Get all environment variables for the build
 def buildEnvVarsMap = build.envVars
 String jobName = buildEnvVarsMap?.JOB_NAME // This is for JOB Name env variable.
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This works, but the only problem is that it ends up using a deprecated method, namely `build.envVars` calls `build.getEnvVars()` which is deprecated.